# Netbeans - Library build with running Glassfish

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, glassfish

I'm using a jar lib, my own develop, to share code between different netbeans project. When I'm going to build lib and glassfish/payara is running i get the following error:

> C:\Users\developer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\redevoserver-git\redevodblib\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1419: Unable to delete file C:\Users\developer\Documents\NetBeansProjects\redevoserver-git\redevodblib\dist\redevolib.jar
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

The annoing procedure now foresee:

1. Stop server;
2. Build lib;
3. Restart server.

This is a great time issue because stop and start glassfish (and redeploy all projects needed) get 60-120 seconds.

Is there a way to manage libraries to avoid server stop need?

Comment: Netbeans Ant command is unable to delete the app files before it redeploys new version, due to file locks in Windows. This is possibly fixed in Payara 162, according to this issue: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/680. Which version of GlassFish/Payara are you using?

Comment: Payara 163 and 164 but I cannot build lib without stopping server